# 2D array initialisation in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I know this is an old chestnut, but I want a small 2D array statically allocated in my code. I know the way to do this is:

```
static int A[3][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
```

That's fine and I can access all the members of it. However I have several problems passing it to a function, e.g.:

```
void print_matrix(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int x, y;

    for(x = 0; x < r; x++)
    {
        printf("Row %02d = %#x = ", x, a[x]);

        for(y = 0; y < c; y++)
        {
            printf("%s%d", (0 == y) ? "" : ", ", a[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Firstly I can't simply pass `A` to the function, I need to cast it to (int **). Since `char *` is synonymous to `char []`, I was a little surprised at this. Secondly, it crashes and when I check in the debugger, within the sub-function, `a[0]` is reported as `1` and not a pointer to an array of integers.

I know there is compiler/C language arcane magic happening here. But it is all a little confusing. If I try to initialise as:

```
static int *A[3] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
```

I get a ton of warnings. How does this differ to:

```
static char *S[3] = { "hello", "there", "stackoverflow" };
```

---

Apart from the question of arcane C magic, which somehow I have never learnt despite over a decade of C programming :(, I would like to know how to generate my array so I can successfully pass it as an `int **` without having to go through all the fag of for loops or copying the statically allocated array to a dynamically allocated one.

Would the following work?

```
int *A0 = { 1, 2 };
int *A1 = { 3, 4 };
int *A2 = { 5, 6 };
int **A = { A0, A1, A2 };
```

Is there a nicer way than this of doing it?

Thanks, all.

P.s. I know that in real life we would read values from a DB or file into dynamically allocated arrays and avoid all this stuff.

Comment: I would begin by consulting [this question in the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) followed by this [entire section](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A multidimensional array does not become a multi-level pointer (I don't know the proper term). Only one dimension decays. For example:

`int [20]` becomes `int *`; `int [20][5]` becomes `int (*)[5]` (which is not `int **`); etc.

If there is a great desire to use multidimensional arrays (via the `[r][c]` syntax), then you have to pass the other bounds (which must be constants). If variable bounds are needed, I think the best option is to perform the index conversion manually (i.e. instead of `a[r][c]`, use `a[r*C + c]`).

Comment: In C99, it's possible to define functions like this: "void f(int c, int a[][c])..." or "void f(int c, int (*a)[c])...". After this, you can index the array like any other multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is to declare argument `a` as `int a[][2]`.

```
void print_matrix(int[][2] a, int r, int c);

// and call the function like this:
print_matrix(A, 3, 2);
```

Comment: this is c, so `void print_matrix(int a[][2], <etc>)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int A0[2] = { 1, 2 };
int A1[2] = { 3, 4 };
int A2[2] = { 5, 6 };
int *A[3] = { A0, A1, A2 };
```

You were close with the last section, but need slightly different declarations.  The resulting A can be passed as an `int **` to a function.

With this, `print_matrix(A, 3, 2);` outputs:

```
Row 00 = 0x5eaeda70 = 1, 2
Row 01 = 0x5eaeda68 = 3, 4
Row 02 = 0x5eaeda60 = 5, 6
```