# error in c language when trying to declare array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, declaration, declare

I am trying to declare this array of strings(or a 2d character array,i reckon) in c language but the compiler ide is giving me error: "[Error] array type has incomplete element type"

```
char division[][]={"Northeast Division","Northwest Division","Southeast Division","Southwest Division"};
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2D array initialisation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409591/2d-array-initialisation-in-c)

Comment: Do you want to be able to modify those "string"s during run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the maximum length of a string. This should solve your problem

```
char division[][25]={"Northeast Division","Northwest Division","Southeast Division","Southwest Division"};
```

Comment: in 1d array you dont need to do that if you given whats in the array...so why do you need to do that in 2d?

Comment: because if we do not specify the row length, then the compiler will have no way of knowing how to deference other row elements. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813494/why-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285028/why-must-n-1-dimensions-be-specified-explicitly-when-initiailizing-an-n-dimensio?noredirect=1&lq=1) for an in depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare like this :

```
char *division[]={"Northeast Division","Northwest Division","Southeast Division","Southwest Division"};
```